# remove line break after </li> and newline with rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, replace, line-breaks, gsub

Trying to remove the linebreak

```
<li>familiar with methodologies like IPMA and Prince;</li>
<br>
```

there is also a new line in there, tried this to no avail ( inside model )

```
  def description
    read_attribute("description").gsub('</li><br>', '</li>')
  end
```

also tried with "\n" what is the correct way to remove the `<br>` after the `</li>` ?

Comment: Question is: why is there a `<br>` after the `<li>` anyway? Is there a linebreak in the description itself? If so, can you remove it with `chomp`?

Answer (score 1):

You used single quotes. If you include the \n, this would not be interpreted as a newline. Instead, you would need something like

```
gsub("</li>\n<br>",'</li>')
```

If the newline is optional, you could do a

```
gsub(%r(</li>\n?<br>),'</li>')
```

Of course you could also catch optional white space in between  or 
, if needed.